# Where can I find the typescript reference for the beta office.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, office-js

I'm wondering where I should look for the typescript definitions file for the beta office JavaScript files at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js and more generally where I should be looking for these files in the future as new versions of the office.js become available?

The NuGet package at https://www.nuget.org/packages/office-js.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/ doesn't have it yet. I found the DefinitelyTyped GitHub project which contains some files, but I also couldn't locate anything for the beta office JavaScript there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @toskv correctly points out for **PRODUCTION** Office.js, you can find the d.ts file on DefinitelyTyped (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/office-js/index.d.ts), also installable via `npm install --save-dev @types/office-js`.

For **BETA**, or any other Office.js flavor, we have recently released a GitHub project and NPM package for Office.js, found at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/.  If you switch over to the `beta` branch, and browse the `dist` folder, you will find an `office.d.ts` file: 
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/blob/beta/dist/office.d.ts.  This file contains the definitions for the beta APIs.  By the way, you can also see the README in that project for how to use this BETA IntelliSense file in Script Lab.

Finally, for both **PRODUCTION AND BETA**, you will *soon* be able to retrieve the Office.d.ts file straight from the CDN:  e.g.,:
http://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.d.ts.  But this is probably a week or two from taking effect.

Comment: I bought the office.js book :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the @types feature you can get them from the npm package corresponding to it.

You can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/office-js).

For the same feature there is a website where you can search for typings, [here](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/).